# Is there a way to open an HTML5 video/stream in a Media Player like VLC/Kodi etc?

Tags: firefox, video, vlc-media-player, streaming, html5

It doesn't seem like it. Seems like HTML5 is proprietary to how that browser implements it. The problem is getting an actual video source/URL for the media players to open.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

In principle, HTML5 media supports all the usual codecs and containers that the browser does.

In practise, though, how the player actually *gets its stream data* can be very complex. Modern JavaScript APIs allow services like YouTube to make range requests, grab stuff from a websocket connection, manipulate streams and buffers on-the-fly all within the webpage/web application. Therefore, if there is no simple URL to access the resource, things get far harder, and to make it work on other 3rd-party players, you'd need a plugin that can handle the transport layer yourself.